# Generate an array of ParametricPlots

Tags: plotting, graphics, matrix

I am editing an old .nb  that generate the polarization map of a vector vortex beam from the Stokes parameters ( S1,S2,S3) stored in 3 different matrices (S1medie,S2medie,S3medie). the code initialize a 900x900 matrix named `finalmatrix`and then replace some elements with 
`Rotate[Circle[{i, j}, {a[S3medie], b[S3medie]}], ψ[S1medie, S2medie]]`. Finally, by applying `Graphics[{Thick, finalmatrix}, ImageSize -> {900, 900}]`,
I get the correct  polarization pattern.

The problem is that, at that time, I used `Rotate[Circle[...]]`to display the ellipses and  it does not allow me to modify the ellipses like I want ( adding a rotating arrow for example ).For this reason I planned to switch to `ParametricPlot`, but when I try to build an equivalent matrix the `Graphics` function doesn't work anymore. I suppose the reason behind this is that the Heads are different since `ParametricPlot` has already head `Graphics`.

I can't post the entire code nor the matrices here but this is the crucial part of it:

```
latocella = 3;
passo = 10;
χ[S3medie_] := ( 1/2 ) ArcSin[Abs[S3medie]];
a[S3medie_] := 8.0*Cos[χ[S3medie]] ;
b[S3medie_] := 8.0*Sin[χ[S3medie]] ;
ψ[S1medie_, S2medie_] := 
  If[S1medie == 0 && S2medie == 0, 0, (1/2) ArcTan [S1medie, S2medie]];
Ellipse[i_, j_, S1medie_, S2medie_, S3medie_] := 
 Rotate[Circle[{i, j}, {a[S3medie], b[S3medie]}], ψ[S1medie, 
   S2medie]]  
fun[i_, j_] := 
 finalmatrix[[j*latocella + (latocella + 1)/2, 
    900 - i*latocella - (latocella + 1)/2]] = 
  Ellipse[j*latocella, 899 - i* latocella, S1medie[[i, j]], 
   S2medie[[i, j]], S3medie[[i, j]]]

finalmatrix = Table[Null, {l, 1, 900}, {k, 1, 900}];
Outer[fun, Range[1, 299, passo], Range[1, 299, passo]];
Graphics[{Thick, finalmatrix}, ImageSize -> {900, 900}]
```

the parametric equation i tried to implement was:

```
ParametricPlot[
 RotationMatrix[ψ[S1medie, S2medie]].{i + 
    8.0*Cos[χ[S3medie]]*Cos[x], 
   j + 8.0*Sin[χ[S3medie]] *Sin[x]} , {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

my questions are:

1)Does anyone know how I can obtain the same result with parametricplot?

2) is it possible to use SparseArray to save  memory ?

3) is there a faster alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your code immensely by placing just a rotated ellipse in each grid point, then using `GraphicsGrid` to render them together:

```
mycircle = 
  GraphicsGroup[{Circle[], Arrowheads[.2], Arrow[{{0, 1}, {0.1, 1}}], 
    White, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2]}];
GraphicsGrid@Table[Graphics[
   GeometricTransformation[mycircle, 
    ShearingTransform[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]
   ], {5}, {5}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks , after few changes it worked like charm.